# The variable netPay keeps saying that it was not initialized

Tags: java, revenue

The variable netPay on

```
System.out.println("\t Regular Pay for 40.0 hour(s): $" + netPay);
```

keep saying that it was not initialized. The only time it works is when I take of the if-else statements.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int employeeNumber;
    double hourlySalary, weeklyTime, netPay, overTime, overTimehours;

    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to \"TEMPLE HUMAN RESOURCES\"");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("\t Enter Employee Number: ");
    employeeNumber=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\t Enter Hourly Salary: ");
    hourlySalary=keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\t Enter Weekly Time: ");
    weeklyTime=keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    overTimehours=weeklyTime-40;
    overTime=(1.5*10)*hourlySalary;

    if (weeklyTime>40) {
        netPay=(weeklyTime*hourlySalary)+(overTime*overTimehours);
    }else if (weeklyTime==40){
        netPay=40*hourlySalary;
    }else {
        overTimehours=0;
        overTime=0;
    }

    System.out.println("\t Employee #: " + employeeNumber);
    System.out.println("\t Hourly Salary: $" + hourlySalary);
    System.out.println("\t Weekly Time: " + weeklyTime + " hour(s)");
    System.out.println("\t Regular Pay for 40.0 hour(s): $" + netPay);
    System.out.println("\t Overtime Pay for " +overTimehours+ " hour(s): $" + overTime);
    System.out.println("\t Net Pay: $" + (overTime+ netPay));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using \"Temple Human Resources\"");
}
```

Comment: double hourlySalary, weeklyTime, netPay, overTime, overTimehours; needs to inilized here

Comment: @KickButtowski *here* is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @hexafraction what do you mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski It can be initialized in a group of if-elseif-else as long as the compiler can guarantee that *every* code path will initialize it. Currently, 2 of the 3 code paths that the OP has will do this.

Comment: @user3558676 is there any need to have netPay in your else block?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that `weeklyTime` was less than 40 (let's say 20 for the sake of an example).

`netPay` is in scope, but neither the `if (weeklyTime>40)` nor the `else if (weeklyTime==40)` blocks will act to initialize it. The `else` block will run, which does not initialize `netPay` at all. You will need to modify your else block to give `netPay` a value. I do not know enough about the rules for calculating the net pay, to know what formula you will want to use in this else block (weeklyTime < 40 being the (implicit) condition to enter it)

Comment: netPay is on those blocks as far as I see

Comment: @KickButtowski Not on the else block. If the weekly time is greater than 40, then the `if` block does the initialization. If the time is equal to 40, then the `else if` block handles it. If the time is less than 40, then execution falls through to the `else` block, which obviously doesn't initialize `netPay`.

Comment: maybe it is not necessary to be in else block ? may be this is logic of the program which indicates no need of netpay in else block

Comment: @KickButtowski Given the existing code the OP has, it would be nonsense to move the initialization out of a self-documenting if-elseif-else group into multiple declarations.

Comment: I still disagree and I just accept what you said because you have higher reputation than me :)

Comment: @KickButtowski Simply trusting someone on reputation alone is *not* the way to go on this site. The choice of where to declare is partially a matter of opinion. While any choice obviously needs to fall within the rules specified by the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/), multiple choices *do* exist, and I do acknowledge that. However, drawing upon my experience and personal opinion, I feel that adding an initialization in the else block makes the most sense from a code-style and semantic standpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61716/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-hexafraction).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because `netPay` is only being initialized in your first two `if` blocks. What if those conditions aren't met? Since you didn't initialize its value when you declared it, and you also didn't set it inside your `else`, then in that case it's not initialized.

What you can do is either initialize it the moment you declared it, something like:

```
double netPay = 0;
```

or set it in your `else` block, like:

```
else {
    overTimehours = 0;
    overTime = 0;
    netPay = 0;
}
```

Comment: all discussion that I have had with hexafraction was about not initialize netPay where it is declared and we do not know the logic of program for else part yet, so we cannot assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, this is what I did and it works.

```
//if there's an overtime or no overtime
if (weeklyTime>40) {
    netPay=(40*hourlySalary)+(overTime*overTimehours);

}
else if (weeklyTime==40){
    netPay=40*hourlySalary;
}
else {
    overTimehours=0;
    overTime=0;

}
//Pay without overtime
    netPay=(weeklyTime-overTimehours)*hourlySalary;
```

I just added it after the if-else statement.